# Como puedo limpiar una cadena de texto que recibo de un web Service

Tags: android, webservice

Tengo un problema cuando recupero una cadena de texto se recupera bien pero tiene algunas etiquetas HTML y caracteres que no quiero mostrar, por ejemplo del siguiente texto solo quiero recuperar el link que esta entre el href, pero no se como puedo extrar ese fragmento o como eliminar todo lo que no necesito, no se si es posible que android interprete las etiquetas HTML.

Este es un ejemplo de como me devuelve las cadenas de texto, solamente quiero conservar el link:

```
 <div><a
 href=\"https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/documento.pdf\"
 class=\"pdfemb-viewer\" style=\"\" data-width=\"max\"
```

Comment: Intentaste añadir una logica tuya para hacerle un split a la cadena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar este método que aplica para obtener el valor de cualquier tag html:

```
private String getUrlFromString(String htmlText, String tag){

    int pos = htmlText.toLowerCase().indexOf(tag) + tag.length() +1;
    String cut1 = htmlText.substring(pos, htmlText.length());

    int pos2 = cut1.indexOf("\"");
    return cut1.substring(0,pos2);

}
```

En este caso de acuerdo a la información que proporcionas, si deseas obtener el valor de la url definida en el tag `href`, lo realizarìas de esta forma:

```
String valorUrl = getUrlFromString(a, "href=");
```

Comment: Tienes Razon, me ayudo mucho, mcuhas gracia

Comment: Un placer ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

por en nombre del sitio veo que estas trabajando con Java, si es de esta manera puedes usar el metodo replaceAll, para eliminar todos los \ cabe señalar que estos se agregan para poder escapar la doble comillas.

```
String ejemplo ="<a href=\"https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/documento.pdf\" class=\"pdfemb-viewer\" style=\"\" data-width=\"max\"";
String replaceString=ejemplo.replace("\\","");//replaces all occurrences of "is" to "was"  
System.out.println(replaceString);
```

resultado